# Moviepy doesn't work after py2exe

Tags: python, py2exe, moviepy

I create an app with pyside and moviepy. It works sucessfully from console (python app.py). When I create exe with py2exe , The app throws that error:

```
File "app.py", line 33, in run
  File "moviepy\editor.pyc", line 22, in <module>
  File "moviepy\video\io\VideoFileClip.pyc", line 3, in <module>
  File "moviepy\video\VideoClip.pyc", line 15, in <module>
  File "numpy\__init__.pyc", line 180, in <module>
  File "numpy\add_newdocs.pyc", line 13, in <module>
  File "numpy\lib\__init__.pyc", line 8, in <module>
  File "numpy\lib\type_check.pyc", line 11, in <module>
  File "numpy\core\__init__.pyc", line 14, in <module>
  File "numpy\core\multiarray.pyc", line 12, in <module>
  File "numpy\core\multiarray.pyc", line 10, in __load
ImportError: DLL load failed:...
```

Exe is working but when I click concatenate videos button in my app it throws error above.

The code which throws error:

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, concatenate_videoclips # line 33 in app.py
clip1 = VideoFileClip(self.fileAbsolutePath)
clip2 = VideoFileClip(self.fileJenerikAbsolutePath)         
final_clip = concatenate_videoclips([clip1,clip2],method="compose")
```

the output of py2exe errors :

```
The following modules appear to be missing
['Carbon', 'Carbon.Files', 'ElementC14N', 'IPython.display', 'Numeric', 'SimpleITK', '__svn_version__', '_curses', '_czifile', '_imp', '_scproxy', '_sysconfigdata', 'astropy.io', 'backports.ssl_match_hostname', 'builtins', 'code_generators.genapi', 'code_generators.numpy_api', 'colorama', 'compat.long', 'configparser', 'copyreg', 'core.BaseProgressIndicator', 'core.Dict', 'core.Format', 'core.FormatManager', 'core.IS_PYPY', 'core.InternetNotAllowedError', 'core.RETURN_BYTES', 'core.StdoutProgressIndicator', 'core.abs', 'core.binary_type', 'core.get_platform', 'core.get_remote_file', 'core.has_module', 'core.image_as_uint8', 'core.load_lib', 'core.max', 'core.min', 'core.read_n_bytes', 'core.resource_dirs', 'core.round', 'core.string_types', 'core.urlopen', 'distutils.ccompiler', 'distutils.cmd', 'distutils.command', 'distutils.command.bdist', 'distutils.command.bdist_rpm', 'distutils.command.build', 'distutils.command.build_clib', 'distutils.command.build_ext', 'distutils.command.build_py', 'distutils.command.build_scripts', 'distutils.command.config', 'distutils.command.install', 'distutils.command.install_data', 'distutils.command.install_headers', 'distutils.command.install_scripts', 'distutils.command.sdist', 'distutils.core', 'distutils.cygwinccompiler', 'distutils.dep_util', 'distutils.dir_util', 'distutils.dist', 'distutils.errors', 'distutils.extension', 'distutils.fancy_getopt', 'distutils.file_util', 'distutils.filelist', 'distutils.log', 'distutils.msvc9compiler', 'distutils.msvccompiler', 'distutils.spawn', 'distutils.sysconfig', 'distutils.unixccompiler', 'distutils.util', 'distutils.version', 'downloader.FileDownloader', 'downloader.get_suitable_downloader', 'dummy.Process', 'extractor._LAZY_LOADER', 'extractor.gen_extractor_classes', 'extractor.gen_extractors', 'extractor.get_info_extractor', 'extractor.list_extractors', 'fcompiler.FCompiler', 'fcompiler.has_f90_header', 'fcompiler.is_f_file', 'genapi', 'html.entities', 'html.parser', 'http.client', 'http.cookiejar', 'http.cookies', 'http.server', 'importlib.machinery', 'lazy_extractors', 'matplotlib', 'matplotlib.pyplot', 'matplotlib.widgets', 'netbios', 'nose', 'nose.plugins', 'nose.plugins.base', 'nose.plugins.builtin', 'nose.plugins.errorclass', 'nose.util', 'numarray', 'numpy._build_utils.apple_accelerate', 'numpy.amax', 'numpy.amin', 'numpy.array', 'numpy.bool_', 'numpy.compat.asbytes', 'numpy.compat.asbytes_nested', 'numpy.compat.asstr', 'numpy.compat.basestring', 'numpy.compat.bytes', 'numpy.compat.integer_types', 'numpy.compat.isfileobj', 'numpy.compat.long', 'numpy.compat.open_latin1', 'numpy.compat.sixu', 'numpy.compat.unicode', 'numpy.core.Inf', 'numpy.core.absolute', 'numpy.core.add', 'numpy.core.all', 'numpy.core.amax', 'numpy.core.amin', 'numpy.core.any', 'numpy.core.arange', 'numpy.core.around', 'numpy.core.array', 'numpy.core.array_repr', 'numpy.core.asanyarray', 'numpy.core.asarray', 'numpy.core.atleast_1d', 'numpy.core.atleast_2d', 'numpy.core.atleast_3d', 'numpy.core.bitwise_and', 'numpy.core.bitwise_or', 'numpy.core.bitwise_xor', 'numpy.core.broadcast', 'numpy.core.cdouble', 'numpy.core.complexfloating', 'numpy.core.concatenate', 'numpy.core.conjugate', 'numpy.core.csingle', 'numpy.core.divide', 'numpy.core.dot', 'numpy.core.double', 'numpy.core.empty', 'numpy.core.empty_like', 'numpy.core.equal', 'numpy.core.errstate', 'numpy.core.fastCopyAndTranspose', 'numpy.core.finfo', 'numpy.core.float32', 'numpy.core.float64', 'numpy.core.float_', 'numpy.core.geterrobj', 'numpy.core.greater', 'numpy.core.greater_equal', 'numpy.core.hstack', 'numpy.core.iinfo', 'numpy.core.inexact', 'numpy.core.inf', 'numpy.core.intc', 'numpy.core.integer', 'numpy.core.intp', 'numpy.core.invert', 'numpy.core.isfinite', 'numpy.core.isinf', 'numpy.core.isnan', 'numpy.core.isscalar', 'numpy.core.left_shift', 'numpy.core.less', 'numpy.core.less_equal', 'numpy.core.linspace', 'numpy.core.longdouble', 'numpy.core.maximum', 'numpy.core.multiply', 'numpy.core.ndarray', 'numpy.core.newaxis', 'numpy.core.not_equal', 'numpy.core.number', 'numpy.core.ones', 'numpy.core.power', 'numpy.core.product', 'numpy.core.ravel', 'numpy.core.remainder', 'numpy.core.reshape', 'numpy.core.result_type', 'numpy.core.right_shift', 'numpy.core.rollaxis', 'numpy.core.shape', 'numpy.core.signbit', 'numpy.core.sin', 'numpy.core.single', 'numpy.core.size', 'numpy.core.sqrt', 'numpy.core.subtract', 'numpy.core.sum', 'numpy.core.swapaxes', 'numpy.core.take', 'numpy.core.transpose', 'numpy.core.ufunc', 'numpy.core.vstack', 'numpy.core.zeros', 'numpy.deprecate', 'numpy.dtype', 'numpy.expand_dims', 'numpy.eye', 'numpy.histogramdd', 'numpy.integer', 'numpy.intp', 'numpy.iscomplexobj', 'numpy.lib.add_newdoc', 'numpy.lib.asfarray', 'numpy.lib.i0', 'numpy.lib.imag', 'numpy.lib.iscomplexobj', 'numpy.lib.real', 'numpy.lib.triu', 'numpy.linalg.eigvals', 'numpy.linalg.inv', 'numpy.linalg.lstsq', 'numpy.ma.MAError', 'numpy.ma.MaskedArray', 'numpy.ma.filled', 'numpy.ma.getdata', 'numpy.ma.getmaskarray', 'numpy.ma.make_mask_descr', 'numpy.ma.masked', 'numpy.ma.masked_array', 'numpy.ma.nomask', 'numpy.ndarray', 'numpy.recarray', 'numpy_api', 'numpy_distutils', 'numpy_distutils.command.build_flib', 'numpy_distutils.command.cpuinfo', 'numpy_distutils.cpuinfo', 'numpy_distutils.fcompiler', 'org.python.modules.posix.PosixModule', 'osgeo.gdal', 'pandas.core.groupby', 'pkg_resources.extern.packaging', 'pkg_resources.extern.six', 'pkg_resources.extern.six.moves', 'postprocessor.FFmpegFixupM3u8PP', 'postprocessor.FFmpegFixupM4aPP', 'postprocessor.FFmpegFixupStretchedPP', 'postprocessor.FFmpegMergerPP', 'postprocessor.FFmpegPostProcessor', 'postprocessor.get_postprocessor', 'pygame', 'scipy', 'setuptools.extern.six', 'setuptools.extern.six.moves', 'setuptools_svn', 'sitecustomize', 'testing.Tester', 'tifffile', 'urllib.error', 'urllib.parse', 'urllib.request', 'urllib.response', 'usercustomize', 'win32com.client.gencache', 'win32pdh', 'win32pipe', 'win32wnet', 'wincertstore', 'winreg', 'xattr']

*** binary dependencies ***
Your executable(s) also depend on these dlls which are not included,
you may or may not need to distribute them.

Make sure you have the license if you distribute any of them, and
make sure you don't distribute files belonging to the operating system.

   OLEAUT32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
   USER32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll
   IMM32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\IMM32.dll
   SHELL32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHELL32.dll
   ole32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\ole32.dll
   COMDLG32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\COMDLG32.dll
   COMCTL32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\COMCTL32.dll
   ADVAPI32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
   WS2_32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2_32.dll
   WINSPOOL.DRV - C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV
   GDI32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\GDI32.dll
   WINMM.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINMM.dll
   KERNEL32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNEL32.dll
```

Comment: What comes after `DLL load failed:`

Comment: @castis just an error text which is in Turkish. It's meaning is "The specified module could not be found"